# How can i invoke the alarm for the past time using alarm manager in android?

Tags: android

i am using alarm manager to invoke the alarm. here i am trying to invoke alarm for the past time means i gave time 10am at i am 11am. The alarm invoke instantly. But i need to invoke it next day 10am. Please provide a way to invoke alarm for the next day or past time.

Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
cal_now.setTime(dat);
cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,5);//set the alarm time
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
if(cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){//if its in the past increment
    cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
}
//SET YOUR AlarmManager here
```

this will solve your problem
in this we compare now time with set time , this ll add one date in your alarm manager

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke it in 23 hours... Not in -1 hours. Past time alarms are invoked instantly

Comment: Please suggest me which method is good alarm.set(,,); or alarm.repeat(,,,);

Comment: If you want the alarm to repeat every fixed time (for example every 24 hours) use alarm.setRepeating. If you want a one time alarm use the other alarm setter.

Comment: can i use this code to invoke alarm for past time
int rem= remaining time;
Handler h=new Handler();
h.postDelayed(r, rem);  //here rem value is remaining time to invoke the alarm


 Runnable r=new Runnable(){
 @Override
 public void run() {
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmObject.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, sender);

 }
}
or the is any other way to set the past time for the alarm using alarmobject? Please suggest me.