# alarm manager is work now if give past time

Tags: android, scheduling, alarmmanager

m taking time from time picker and when i set scheduling time to do work, it creating problem

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CONSTANT_FILE_NAME",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor=   prefs.edit();
             editor.putLong("timepickerhour", timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                editor.putLong("timepickerminute", timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                editor.putLong("milis", milis);
                editor.commit();



    SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("CONSTANT_FILE_NAME",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                h =prfs.getLong("timepickerhour",0); 
                m =prfs.getLong("timepickerminute",0); 
                r =prfs.getLong("milis",0);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Scheduling.this, Feedback.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Scheduling.this, 0,
                  intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) h);
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) m);
                am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),
                        r, pendingIntent);
```

m facing problem when i give past time then now, as like now time is 4:25 pm if i set time 2:25 pm then that scheduling task run on the spot......
also problem if now time is 4:38 pm and i set time 4:38 am then also run code also now

plz help me

thnks in advance

same problem like this 
[How can i invoke the alarm for the past time using alarm manager in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361835/how-can-i-invoke-the-alarm-for-the-past-time-using-alarm-manager-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (calendar1.before(cal_now)) {// if its in the past increment
                    calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line I think You will get right time:---

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: sir m taking time from from time picker, which will set by user

Comment: i add that line , bt my application has stoped their full work